# Windows webview cross domain issue

Tags: windows, uwp

I am developing windows app.I need to call cross domain api from webview. And i dont have any access in that domain. That is third party domain. So How to do ajax call?

Comment: Welcome to stack-overflow take a tour [Go through How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which helps you for more view s and some Answers .

Comment: There is a document about the [XMLHTTPRequest (XHR) and AJAX Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh767445.aspx), please check it.